# Can pop-ups open as tabs in Safari iOS?

Tags: ipad

Can pop-ups open as tabs in browser windows? This is on an iPad and Safari.

Comment: Can you give an example?  Is the pop up a whole new window or is it contained in the window which you are browsing?

Answer (score 0):

**Well, yes the pop ups in Safari open in a new window if you allow them to do it.** You normally have a choice between "Allow" and "Block". If you "Allow", it will simply open the pop up in a new tab on the same window. But sometimes, you have a choice between "Open" and "Cancel" which means, that if you "Open", it will open in the indicated app.

Examples:

1. Allow/Block
   [image: Allow/Block]
2. Open/Cancel
   [image: Open/Cancel]

NOTE: In **bold** is the answer to your question, the rest is specification.